# X-Forwarded-Host contains wrong virtualhost

Tags: apache2

I have an Apache server acting as a reverse proxy in which two identical virtualhosts are configured: server1 and server2 (see below). There is a CNAME DNS record for server2.mydomain.com which points to server1.mydomain.com. When I hit http://*server1*.mydomain.com/some/resource, the back-end server sees an X-Forwarded-Host header containing *server2*.mydomain.com.  Is this a bug or is my configuration incorrect?

Thanks.

-b

Here's what my virtualhosts look like:

non-SSL (rewrites to SSL)

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName server1.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias server1
    ServerSignature off

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName server2.mydomain.com
    ServerAlias server2
    ServerSignature off

    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
    RewriteRule (.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI}
</VirtualHost>
```

SSL

```
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName server1.mydomain.com
    ServerSignature off

    DocumentRoot ...

    <Directory ... />

    Header        edit Location ^http:(.*)$ https:$1
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

    ProxyVia off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://back-end.mydomin.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://back-end.mydomain.com/

    ...
<VirtualHost>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    ServerAdmin webmaster@localhost
    ServerName server2.mydomain.com
    ServerSignature off

    DocumentRoot ...

    <Directory ... />

    Header        edit Location ^http:(.*)$ https:$1
    RequestHeader set X-Forwarded-Proto https

    ProxyVia off
    ProxyRequests Off
    ProxyPreserveHost On

    SSLProxyEngine On
    ProxyPass / https://back-end.mydomin.com/
    ProxyPassReverse / https://back-end.mydomain.com/

    ...
<VirtualHost>
```

Answer (score 1):

My bad.  I had overlapping SSL virtualhosts (didn't notice the warning when I started/stopped Apache).  Resolution was to add **NameVirtualHost *:443** to ports.conf

-b